# Attribute querying not casting to base type of attribute, what gives?

Tags: c#, reflection, attributes

I'm trying to query attributes and access the base type of several attributes. For some reason it is failing to cast properly and not executing as expected.  Here is the code below:

```
    internal static void ValidateProperties(TModel model, ModelStateDictionary modelState)
    {
        Type type = model.GetType();            
        PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties();
        foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
        {                
            foreach(Attribute attribute in property.GetCustomAttributes(true))
            {
                ValidationAttribute validationAttribute = attribute as ValidationAttribute;
                if (validationAttribute != null)
                {                        
                    if (!validationAttribute.IsValid(property.GetValue(model, null)))
                        modelState.AddModelError(property.Name, validationAttribute.ErrorMessage);
                }
            }
        }            
    }
```

For some reason validateAttribute is always null.  In debugging it won't cast CustomValidationAttribute or RequiredAttribute.  Trying to directly cast to ValidationAttribute instead of using the "as" keyword results in an Invalid Cast exception for both of these types as well.  Clearly they are derived from ValidationAttribute: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationattribute.aspx

What am I missing?  Thanks!

---

Edit:  Per request, I've added an Debug statement to output the Type of the Attribute.  The results are as follows:

System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.CustomValidationAttribute
System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.RequiredAttribute
System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.RegularExpressionAttribute
System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.CustomValidationAttribute
System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.RequiredAttribute

Comment: To confirm that the attributes that are failing to cast are definitely the validation attributes, could you log attribute.GetType().FullName at the top of the foreach loop and post the results?

Comment: Sure thing, original post has been edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like you're missing anything or doing anything wrong, so here's a shot in the dark: are the assemblies (the one querying and the one being queried) using different (strong-named) versions of the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll?

Comment: That's a good guess. The function above is in a different assembly than the ones being passed into it. I'll have to check on this when I get home today.

Comment: Ding ding ding!  Nailed it.  I forgot that the MVC app was using a the MVC DataAnnotations version of System.ComopondentModel.DataAnnotations. In the other assembly I referenced from the .NET Framework. Problem resolved when I used the MVC DataAnnotations version in the other assembly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

Before actually casting please do type-check for Attribute.

Instead of directly casting..

```
ValidationAttribute validationAttribute = attribute as ValidationAttribute;
```

Check..

```
if(!(attribute is ValidationAttribute))
{
    continue;
}
ValidationAttribute validationAttribute = attribute as ValidationAttribute;
```

**Original:**

This is how you can do this.

> **Why iterate through all attributes of a property, instead filter all
>   properties having attribute of type
>   ValidationAttribute.**

```
        PropertyInfo[] properties = model.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

        var valProps = from PropertyInfo property in properties
                       where property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ValidationAttribute), true).Length > 0
                       select new
                       {
                           Property = property,
                           ValidationAttributes = property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ValidationAttribute), true)
                       };

        foreach (var item in valProps)
        {
            foreach (ValidationAttribute attribute in item.ValidationAttributes)
            {
                if (attribute.IsValid(item.Property.GetValue(model, null)))
                {
                    continue;
                }

                //Validation fails..
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: That was my original technique.  It was not finding any properties that had a ValidationAttribute.  I changed it to the code above to diagnose exactly where the error was occurring.  Regardless, the code you posted does not work either, valProps contains 0 records.